# Как запустить несколько Node.js-скриптов параллельно?

Tags: node.js, bash, процесс, распараллеливание

Например как запустить два Node.js-скрипта параллельно?

```
#!/bin/bash
node ./scriptOne.js
node ./scriptTwo.js
```

Comment: может это Вам поможет - https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/child_process.html

Comment: поставить в конце каждой строки символ `&`, отделив его пробелом. `node ./scriptOne.js &` `node ./scriptTwo.js &`. Они будут полностью отдельными, с разными PID, работать параллельно.